# plot 2 datasets in one bar chart using ggplot, and x-axis keeps the two datasets separate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets: services and disservices from trees. I want to graph them both on the same bar chart, which I've been able to do, but I want them to still have separate labels on the x-axis.

Each dataset is in a different color, so basically, I want the light green to be together and the dark green to be together.

R is arranging them alphabetically, so they end up interspersed with each other, and I'm not sure how to fix this. I've experimented with labels, fct_reorder, and was also trying to see if this is something I could do with a scale_x_ function, but all I have done is mess up the y-axis or had no change at all. I'm still on a learning curve with R, though.

The two datasets I'm working with are below - it's the agree column that I'm graphing (it's percent).

```
**dssNeighbor**
  DSS                                                            count total agree
  <chr>                                                          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Trees drip sap on parked cars                                     25   107 0.234
2 Trees drop leaves and seeds                                       38   106 0.358
3 Trees damage sidewalks                                            44   107 0.411
4 Trees damage sewer pipes                                          47   105 0.448
5 Trees are dangerous (falling branches, falling on power lines)    39   106 0.368
6 Trees make it hard to see crime happening                         21   107 0.196


**essNeighbor**
 ESS                                                       count total agree
   <chr>                                                     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Trees create shade                                          108   110  98.2
 2 Trees reduce building energy costs                          105   110  95.5
 3 Trees help people feel calmer                               109   110  99.1
 4 Trees help reduce flooding                                   97   107  90.7
 5 I like the birds and animals that they attract              108   110  98.2
 6 Trees are beautiful                                         109   109 100  
 7 I like the seasonal differences in them (flowers, leaves)   108   109  99.1
 8 Trees cool the air                                          108   109  99.1
 9 Trees help reduce air pollution                             106   108  98.1
10 Trees help improve water quality                            103   108  95.4
```

**This is the graph that I get:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to create one dataset using e.g. `dpylr::bind_rows` and use faceting which allows to group the statements by type. Additionally you could use `reorder` or `fit_reorder` to order the statements by the percentage of respondents who agreed. Finally, especially with long labels I would suggest to switch to a horizontal barchart.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

neighbor <- bind_rows(
  list(
    DSS = dssNeighbor,
    ESS = essNeighbor
  ),
  .id = "service"
) |>
  mutate(
    statement = coalesce(DSS, ESS),
    .keep = "unused"
  ) |>
  mutate(
    agree = count / total
  ) |>
  mutate(
    statement = reorder(statement, agree),
    service = factor(service, c("ESS", "DSS"))
  )

head(neighbor)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   service count total agree statement                                           
#>   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>                                               
#> 1 DSS        25   107 0.234 Trees drip sap on parked cars                       
#> 2 DSS        38   106 0.358 Trees drop leaves and seeds                         
#> 3 DSS        44   107 0.411 Trees damage sidewalks                              
#> 4 DSS        47   105 0.448 Trees damage sewer pipes                            
#> 5 DSS        39   106 0.368 Trees are dangerous (falling branches, falling on p…
#> 6 DSS        21   107 0.196 Trees make it hard to see crime happening

ggplot(neighbor, aes(agree, statement, fill = service)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(ESS = "lightgreen", DSS = "forestgreen")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_percent(),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = ~ gsub("\\(.*?\\)", "", .x)
  ) +
  facet_grid(service ~ .,
    scales = "free_y",
    space = "free_y",
    switch = "y",
    labeller = labeller(
      service = c(
        ESS = "Ecosystem Services",
        DSS = "Ecosystem Disservices"
      )
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    plot.margin = margin(
      5.5, 22, 5.5, 5.5
    ),
    panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"),
    axis.line = element_line(linewidth = .5)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "People who agreed with each Statement (percent)",
    y = NULL
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dssNeighbor <- tibble::tibble(
  DSS = c(
    "Trees drip sap on parked cars",
    "Trees drop leaves and seeds",
    "Trees damage sidewalks",
    "Trees damage sewer pipes",
    "Trees are dangerous (falling branches, falling on power lines)",
    "Trees make it hard to see crime happening"
  ),
  count = c(25, 38, 44, 47, 39, 21),
  total = c(107, 106, 107, 105, 106, 107),
  agree = c(0.234, 0.358, 0.411, 0.448, 0.368, 0.196)
)

essNeighbor <- tibble::tibble(
  ESS = c(
    "Trees create shade",
    "Trees reduce building energy costs",
    "Trees help people feel calmer",
    "Trees help reduce flooding",
    "I like the birds and animals that they attract",
    "Trees are beautiful",
    "I like the seasonal differences in them (flowers, leaves)",
    "Trees cool the air",
    "Trees help reduce air pollution",
    "Trees help improve water quality"
  ),
  count = c(108, 105, 109, 97, 108, 109, 108, 108, 106, 103),
  total = c(110, 110, 110, 107, 110, 109, 109, 109, 108, 108),
  agree = c(98.2, 95.5, 99.1, 90.7, 98.2, 100, 99.1, 99.1, 98.1, 95.4)
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your code worked perfectly and I don't know how long it would have taken me to figure this out (or if I ever would have). I spent HOURS on this, so I really appreciate your help!